# How do you uninstall Google Cloud Platform app from project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-identity

I wanted to test out the GCP "Identity Providers" app with an existing projected that I use for OAuth.

I went through the whole process of installing and setting up a payment method before realizing that I was installing the app to under my organization Google account and the organization's GCP project. This includes adding my personal payment information to my work Google account.

I can't for the life of my figure out how to uninstall the "Identity Providers" GCP app from the project.

How can I uninstall a GCP app from a project?

Comment: What's that "project"?

Comment: The "project" is what the GCP app was installed too. You create projects under organizations and use them for stuff. I'm new to the GCP ecosystem so I apologize if my terminology is incorrect.